# Calculating current, min, max, mean monthly growth from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset similar to the one below:

```
product_ID month amount_sold
1          1     23          
1          2     34          
1          3     85          
2          1     47          
2          2     28          
2          3     9           
3          1     73          
3          2     84          
3          3     12
```

I want the output to be like this:

For example, for **product 1**:

-`avg_monthly_growth` is calculated by ((85-34)/34*100 + (34-23)/23*100)/2 = 98.91%

-`lowest_monthly_growth` is (34-23)/23*100) = 47.83%

-`highest_monthly_growth` is (85-34)/34*100) = 150%

-`current_monthly_growth` is the growth between the lastest two months (in this case, it's the growth from month 2 to month 3, as the `month` ranges from 1-3 for each product)

```
product_ID avg_monthly_growth lowest_monthly_growth highest_monthly_growth current_monthly_growth
1          98.91%             47.83%                150%                   150%
2          ...                ...                   ...                    ...
3          ...                ...                   ...                    ...
```

I've tried `df.loc[df.groupby('product_ID')['amount_sold'].idxmax(), :].reset_index()` which gets me the max (and similarly the min), but I'm not too sure how to get the percentage growths.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what went wrong with your attempt?

Comment: `new_df = df.groupby('product_ID').amount_sold.pct_change()` and then another `new_df.groupby'product_ID').agg({'mean','min','max'})`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `pivot_table` withh `pct_change()` on `axis=1` , then create a dictionary with desired series and create a df:

```
m=df.pivot_table(index='product_ID',columns='month',values='amount_sold').pct_change(axis=1)
d={'avg_monthly_growth':m.mean(axis=1)*100,'lowest_monthly_growth':m.min(1)*100,
   'highest_monthly_growth':m.max(1)*100,'current_monthly_growth':m.iloc[:,-1]*100}
final=pd.DataFrame(d)
print(final)
```

---

```
             avg_monthly_growth  lowest_monthly_growth  highest_monthly_growth  \
product_ID                                                                      
1                    98.913043              47.826087              150.000000   
2                   -54.141337             -67.857143              -40.425532   
3                   -35.322896             -85.714286               15.068493   

            current_monthly_growth  
product_ID                          
1                       150.000000  
2                       -67.857143  
3                       -85.714286
```

Comment: Thanks very much! By the way, what if I wanted to do this for more than one metric? e.g. I added another metric called 'money_made', `m=df.pivot_table(index='product_ID',columns='month',values=['amount_sold', 'money_made').pct_change(axis=1)`. How can I read this into the dictionary along with amount_sold? And output avg,min,max,current for both of these?